# MIPS Asm: How are things pushed to the stack and how exactly does this affect $sp?

Tags: assembly, mips

With MIPS, I am trying to understand how the stack works.  I basically have it down except one thing.  Let's say we have a macro for pushing a value onto the stack like so:

```
.macro PUSHI_    %0

        li      $t0, %0             #loads the value into register $t0                   
        addi    $sp, $sp, -4        #increments the stack pointer
        sw      $t0, ($sp)          #Here is where I need help
.end_macro
```

I don't really understand the syntax for that line above.  "sw" is for when you want to store the value in a register into memory, but in this case what is going on with the second parameter? I thought $sp was supposed to point to the top of the stack. Is it storing the *address* into $sp?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The stack is in memory at address `$sp`. So `sw $t0, ($sp)` writes the value in `$t0` into memory at address `$sp`, that is it puts the item on the top of stack. Growing the stack has been previously done by the `addi $sp, $sp, -4` (stack grows down).

Comment: @Jester Thanks for the help. I wasn't thinking about the fact that you could pass in an address as a parameter there.  Is that denoted by the parentheses? because otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, the parentheses indicate indirection. In any case, `sw` writes to memory, so `sw $t0, $sp` is invalid. The parentheses is just a visual helper so it is obvious that it's a memory address.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to add a pseudo-comment (can't comment yet), there would have been a previous instruction in the code where an address was loaded into $sp. 
For instance, in WinMIPS64, the stack is located at the memory address 1024 or 0x400*. So earlier on in the program you would have an instruction like this:

```
daddi $sp,  $sp, 0x400 #loads the immediate value 0x400 into the $sp register.
```

This is why you can use it as a pointer, in that fashion. When you say:

```
sw $t0, ($sp)
```

It is saying - store the value which is in temporary register $t0, in the memory address pointed at by the register $sp.

*This is likely a different address in the MIPS you are using. It looks like a you are using MIPS32 version of some kind, from the type of instructions, but hopefully you get the point.

Comment: More normally (when running under an OS at least), your program starts with `$sp` pointing to the top of a valid chunk of memory you can use for stack space.  And BTW, the majority of MIPS questions on SO are using the MARS or SPIM simulators with 32-bit MIPS code.  Note that MIPS32 is actually a specific version of the MIPS ISA, and doesn't just mean 32-bit MIPS.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64  - MIPS32 is the 32-bit subset of MIPS V with all 64-bit instructions removed.  Unlike x86, MIPS doesn't separate 32 vs. 64-bit modes, but some code chooses not to use 64